# The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper' threw an exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, xaf

I have myExe472.exe that calls myNet472 dll that calls a mystandard2 dll  ( i.e standard2.0) which uses entityframeworkcore
This works fine.

However when I try and use myNet472 in a different .exe (a Dev Express xaf module.win project) I get an error

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=VivUniversalController Load line 20 System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper' threw an exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Failed to load D:\dev\Viv.MyApp2\MyApp2.Win\bin\Debug\x64\SNI.dll ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified module could not be found
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper..cctor() in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\Interop\SNINativeMethodWrapper.cs:line 67
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIInitialize()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..ctor() in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParserSafeHandles.cs:line 36
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..cctor() in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParserSafeHandles.cs:line 17
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..cctor() in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 166
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..ctor(Boolean MARS, Boolean fAsynchronous) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 33
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 1743
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 1628
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback, ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, SqlClientOriginalNetworkAddressInfo originalNetworkAddressInfo, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 465
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnectionFactory.cs:line 145
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionFactory.cs:line 167
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 955
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 2024
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 1427
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 1309
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionFactory.cs:line 357
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionInternal.cs:line 773
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 1876
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 1853
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 1421
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at SBD.VivSnap.Data.DataAccess.GetJob(Int32 JobId)
   at SBD.VivSnap.SnapIns.UniversalSnapIn.VivUniversalController.Load(Int32 jobId) System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper' threw an exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Failed to load D:\dev\Viv.MyApp2\MyApp2.Win\bin\Debug\x64\SNI.dll ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified module could not be found
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper..cctor() in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\Interop\SNINativeMethodWrapper.cs:line 67
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIInitialize()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..ctor() in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParserSafeHandles.cs:line 36
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..cctor() in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParserSafeHandles.cs:line 17
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..cctor() in H:\tsaagent4\_work\2\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 166
  Source=SBD.VivSnap.SnapIns
  StackTrace:
   at SBD.VivSnap.SnapIns.UniversalSnapIn.VivUniversalController.Load(Int32 jobId)
   at VIV.MyApp2.Module.Win.Controllers.AcmeResultObjectViewController.View_CreateCustomCurrentObjectDetailView(Object sender, CreateCustomCurrentObjectDetailViewEventArgs e) in D:\dev\Viv.MyApp2\MyApp2.Module.Win\Controllers\AcmeResultObjectViewController.cs:line 52
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ListView.UpdateEditFrame(Object currentObject)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.ListView.DoOnListEditorFocusedObjectChanged()
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Editors.ListEditor.RaiseFocusedObjectChanged()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Editors.ListEditor.UnlockSelectionEvents()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Editors.WinColumnsListEditor.gridDataSourceManager_DataSourceChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Editors.XafGridControlDataSourceAdapter.OnControlDataSourceChanged()
   at DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Editors.XafGridControlDataSourceAdapter.<AssignDataSourceToGridControl>d__7.MoveNext()
```

I dont understand why this file is needed since it is not needed in the non xaf application.

I made a new xaf winforms Entity Framework application and tried calling mystandard2 from an action on a viewcontroller

This time the error is

```
System.Exception: 'VivUniversalController Load line 20 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache..ctor(IOptions`1 optionsAccessor, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_8(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at SBD.VivSnap.Data.DataAccess.GetJob(Int32 JobId)
   at SBD.VivSnap.SnapIns.UniversalSnapIn.VivUniversalController.Load(Int32 jobId)

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///d:/Users/kirst/source/repos/Bells/Bells.Win/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: d:\Users\kirst\source\repos\Bells\Bells.Win\bin\Debug\Bells.Win.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///d:/Users/kirst/source/repos/Bells/Bells.Win/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///d:/Users/kirst/source/repos/Bells/Bells.Win/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///d:/Users/kirst/source/repos/Bells/Bells.Win/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///d:/Users/kirst/source/repos/Bells/Bells.Win/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.EXE.
 '
```

Interestingly when I add the  mystandard2 reference to the xaf .win project the code runs correctly.

Comment: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t898134/when-referencing-external-dlls-it-seems-necessary-to-include-them-in-the-wn-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to put the reference to mystandard2 library in the xaf .win project as well.

Answer (score 5):

all project must include [`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/) reference

[More info](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/361#issuecomment-569026464)

Comment: That was it! Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 1):

I received this error only when running unit tests.  Solved by including the external reference via Nuget from the test project, even though it's not directly called in the test project.